# PHP user-level session persistence

Tags: php, apache, session, testing

I have a use case where I need to be able to access my site from the local server. Specifically, it's for a HTML-to-PDF export of parts of various pages, but this would be nice for testing parts of the website as well.

The problem is that we have a login splash page, which needs to be dealt with before I can access any parts of the website.  It would be really nice if I could just call a command `"wkhtml2pdf 'localhost/[myurl]'"` and have it PDF some stuff, but it hits this splash page.

Is there some way that I can perma-persist just one single session on the server?  Or enable login-less access from localhost?  Or could I just add a new Apache entry that accesses our site, whitelists only localhost and somehow circumvents the login?

What's the best solution?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. One potentially obvious one is to separate your logic and views such that it's possible to trigger generation of the HTML you want without also triggering a splash screen. Another possibility is not to display the splash screen if the user's IP is 127.0.0.1. There are plenty of options.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your session cookie as parameter in wkhtml2pdf to solve your problem.
You can also execute it from a php file like this.

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf --cookie '{$cookieName}' '{$cookieValue}' http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Soliciting feedback on this solution now:
I whitelisted localhost via `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in the login scripts to bypass the usual user authentication and get an automatic localhost-user login.  The server is running, however, on a university LAN, so the LAN maybe really big, possibly enabling bidirectional TCP spoofing.
Should I be worried about this, or does someone need admin rights on the routers or something?  I trust the IT folks, but not others.

I realize that this sounds like a separate question, but I feel that security relates to whether or not this is a good solution.

Comment: Re *"Should I be worried about this, or does someone need admin rights on the routers or something?"*: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). Questions do not belong in answers.